# Powershell: add new line in Email doesent work

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to check disks and send an e-mail with the status.

But all I get is a body in one Line instead of `'r'n`. What is wrong?

```
$smtpserver = "server"
$from = "from"
$to = "to"
$subject = "subject"

$servernames = Get-Content "C:\computer.txt"

$Diskreport = $Servernames | % {
    Get-WmiObject Win32-LogicalDisk -Computername $_ -Filter "Drivetype=3" -ErrorAction SilentContinue |
        ? { ($_.freespace/$size) -le '0.7' }
}

[String]$body = $null
$DiskReport | % {
    $body += (Servername: "+$_.SystemName) + "'r'n"
    $body += (Drive Letter: "+$_.DeviceID.ToString()) + "'r'n"
    $body += (TotalCapacity (GB): "+((($_.size /1024) /1000) /1000).ToString()) + "'r'n"
    $body += (TotalCapacity (GB): "+((($_.Freespace /1024) /1000) /1000).ToString()) + "'r'n"
    $body += (TotalCapacity (GB): "+($Freespace /$_.size).ToString()) 
}

Send-MailMessage -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -From $from -To $to -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Port 587
```

Comment: Looks like you got the rong escape character. It's the **backtick** character: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6

Comment: The code in your question is broken and can't possibly work. Please create a [mcve] that actually demonstrates your problem, then [edit] your question and post *that* code along with samples of desired and actual output. Do not post code you fabricated or typed from memory.

Comment: Considering that it should be `Win32_LogicalDisk` not `Win32-LogicalDisk` and `SilentlyContinue` not `SilentContinue`,  `? { ($_.freespace/$_.size) -le 0.7}` not `? { ($_.freespace/$size) -le '0.7' }` I'm curious what output you do get in fact?

Answer (score 1):

The string `"'r'n"` is just four normal characters - a single-quotation mark, an `r`, a single-quotation mark, and an `n`.

If you want a carriage return and a line feed in the string, [use a backtick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6#new-line-n) (`` ` ``) to escape `r` and `n`, [as pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195959/powershell-add-new-line-in-email-doesent-work/54196133#comment95218775_54195959):

```
$body += "(Servername: " + $_.SystemName + ")`r`n" # and so on...
```

---

An alternative approach would be to just use the `-join` operator to join all the lines by `[Environment]::NewLine`:

```
$bodyLines = @(
    "(Servername: $($_.SystemName))"
    "(Drive Letter: $($_.DeviceID.ToString()))"
    # etc...
)
$body += $bodyLines -join [Environment]::NewLine
```

Comment: Thank your for your help. But it doesnt work  either the `, i 'm trying to do another solution :)

Comment: Tested it. Works fine. (Just as expected) @Chewie Check if you send as Html? Even though your example doesn't show that.